# How to I train my dog to stop digging on the sofa?

Tags: dogs, behavior, training

My dog digs. It's not to sharpen his claws. He is anxious. The older dad dog was fine for 1 yr, in his new home with me but then he decided to dig and destroy my entire sofa. He looked guilty and I saw him so I know he did this. I want to buy a new sofa, how do I ease his need to dig my sofa? He has toys and 2 beds. Is there an anti anxiety medication that would work??

Comment: Related if not a duplicate of http://pets.stackexchange.com/q/179/41

Answer (score 1):

<strike>This is perfectly normal for a 1 year old dog to be explorative, active, and want to use his tools for fun.</strike>

1. Wear him out daily with lots of exercise. He's digging on the couch
   because it's fun and he isn't tired.
2. Provide him with a location in which he *can* dig because he needs a healthy  approved outlet.
3. Sure you could dope him with meds instead of giving him proper care and attention... **not**. It's unlikely he is doing this because he has anxiety - it is much more likely he isn't getting a proper amount of exercise. Dogs need as much and usually more exercise than we do.
4. Toss a dog blanket over the couch before he hops up.

Comment: He usually digs the sofa when settling in for a nap..... he's fluffing it up to be more comfortable,    it's frustrating.  And he's 14

Answer (score 0):

When your in the house don't let him on the sofa simply tell him (no) then eventually when your out he should know he's not aloud on there. My bitch does this just randomly starts digging.